# Exercise of group theory, every element of the group can be written in a particular way

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

I have to solve the following exercise:

> Let $G$ be a group of order $24$ which has a cyclic subgroup $H=G(\alpha)$ of order $12$ and we take an element $x \in G \setminus H$. We have to prove that each element $g \in G$ can be written in a unique way as $x^i\alpha^j$ for $i=0,1$ and $j=0,\ldots,11$.

My question is, if I take the cyclic subgroup $X=G(x)$, can happen that $X \cap H \neq \{e\}$? Where $e$ is the unit of the group. Another question is: to solve this exercice, I have to prove that $G=XH$? $H$ is a normal subgroup, so $XH$ is a subgroup of $G$.

Comment: Please use more descriptive titles

Comment: Sure. If $G$ is a cyclic group of order $24,$ then $X=G$ is possible.

Comment: And if $G$ is not cyclic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two cosets: $H$ and $G\setminus H$. It implies that both the left and right cosets of $x$ are $xH=G\setminus H=Hx$.

If the given element $g$ is in $H$, then there's a unique exponent $j<12$ such that $g=\alpha^j$ because $H$ is cyclic of order $12$ generated by $\alpha$.

In the other case, $g=xh$ for some $h\in H$ because $g$ is in the (left) coset of $x$, so again, $g=x\alpha^j$ for a unique $j<12$.

Since every element can be written as $x^i\alpha^j$, it readily follows that $G=\langle x\rangle\,H$.

Comment: It is clear, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

We can show this directly, for those who have not learned about cosets. All one needs is the following: First, if $j$ is an integer not divisible by $12$, then $\alpha^j \not = e$. Then, $x \not \in H$ gives $x \not = \alpha^j$ for any $j=\{0,1\ldots, 11\}$, and therefore, as $H$ is a group, $x^{-1} \not \in H$, and so $x^{-1}\not = \alpha^j$ for any $j=\{0,1\ldots, 11\}$.

In fact, each element in $G$ can be written $x^i\alpha^j$, where $i \in \{0,1\}$ and $j \in \{0,1,\ldots, 11\}$.

We show this by showing the following:

> Claim 1: There are exactly $24$ elements $g \in G$ that can be written $g=x^i\alpha^j$, for some $i \in \{0,1\}$ and $j \in \{0,1,\ldots, 11\}$. In other words, let $(i,j)$ and $(i',j')$ be *distinct* ordered pairs satisfying $i,i' \in \{0,1\}$; $j,j' \in \{0,1, \ldots, 11\}$. Then $x^{i'}\alpha^{j'} \not = x^i \alpha^j$.

Proof of Claim 1: Suppose $x^i\alpha^j=x^{i'}\alpha^{j'}$. Then left-multiplying both sides by $\alpha^{-j}$ gives $x^i = x^{i'}\alpha^{j'-j}$. We go through the cases:

1. If the equation $j'=j$ holds then this gives $x^i=x^{i'}$ which gives $i=i'$ [lest $x=e$]. So if both of the equations $x^i\alpha^j=x^{i'}\alpha^{j'}$ and $j=j'$ hold, then so must the equation $i=i'$, which means that $(i,j)$ and $(i',j')$ are the same ordered pair.
2. If $j$ and $j'$ are not the same, then right-multiplying both sides of the equation $x^i = x^{i'}\alpha^{j'-j}$ by $x^{-i}$ gives $e=x^{i-i'}\alpha^{j'-j}$. If $i$ and $i'$ are the same then this gives $e=\alpha^{j-j'}$ which would be impossible for such $j,j'$ [because $\alpha$ has order $12$]. If $i$ and $i'$ are not the same then this would give either $e = x\alpha^{j'-j}$ or $e=x^{-1}\alpha^{j'-j}$, which would give $x \in H$ or $x^{-1} \in H$ which in turn would imply $x \in H$, which is false.

So Claim 1 follows . $\surd$

Claim 1 and the Pigeonhole Principle mean then that it is all $24$ elements $g \in G$ that can be written $g=x^i\alpha^j$ for some $i \in \{0,1\}$ and some $j \in \{0,1,\ldots, 11\}$, and for each such $g$, there is exactly one way to write $g$ in the above form.

Comment: It is clear, thank you!